# NHibernate 3 throwing NotSupportedException with SQL Compact 4.0 and FirstOrDefault()

Tags: linq, nhibernate, sql-server-ce

I have a fairly simple piece of code that retrieves an object from the DB.  This seems to work fine with SQL Server 2008, but blows up with SQL Server Compact.  SQL Server CE supports TOP() - is this just a bug in NHibernate 3?

Code:

```
public override Profile GetProfileByName(string name)
{
    using (var tc = TC)
    {
        var query = from profiles in tc.Session.Query<Profile>()
                    where profiles.Name == name
                    select profiles;
        Profile profile = query.FirstOrDefault();
        tc.Commit();
        return profile;
    }
}
```

NHibernate Config:

```
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSqlCeDialect</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlServerCeDriver</property>
```

Exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException occurred
  Message=Dialect does not support limits.
  Source=NHibernate
  StackTrace:
       at NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect.GetLimitString(SqlString queryString, Nullable`1 offset, Nullable`1 limit, Parameter offsetParameter, Parameter limitParameter)
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong dialect. Use `MsSqlCe40Dialect`.

Comment: I switched to MsSqlCe40Dialect and it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I've just tried your code and it works fine. Are you using the latest version (3.2 GA)? If it "doesn't make a difference" you probably forgot to compile or deploy, because MsSqlCe40Dialect implements exactly that one feature (paging). I know because I'm the original autor :-)

Comment: I have version 3.2.0.4000 of NHibernate.dll, let me play around with this a bit more and make sure that my change to the config.xml is being read.

Comment: It works!  I must not have copied the configuration xml to the output folder before testing again.  Thanks! (both for your answer, and for your NHibernate contribution to support it in the first place)

Answer (score 1):

For me MsSqlCe40Dialect is not working, i had to override SupportsVariableLimit in a custom dialect to get paging work.

```
public class MyDialect : MsSqlCe40Dialect
{
    public override bool SupportsVariableLimit
    {
        get
        {
            return true; 
        }
    }
}
```